# Force safari to always display the top bar on smartphones

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I'm developing a website for smartphone and I'm having some issues with the top safari bar. I would like to always display it in portrait and landscape.

On a page, I do have a link animation. When I'm clicking on it, the browser is removing the top bar. Is there a way to let the top bar during the animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari automatically slides the browser top bar up on iPhones and iPod touches asoon as the page is scrolled, even by a single pixel.

The only way to get around this would to have a div that fills the screen with css property overflow:hidden but you would have to control movement of the content.